# R : Converting "Daily" time series to monthly

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am working with time series data (6000 observations, over 7000 days) that is said to be "daily". However, measurements do not necessarily happen everyday. Sometimes, several measurements can happen on the same day. This is why I think it would be better to analyze this data "monthly" instead of "daily".

I create some dummy data that represents my time series:

```
library(xts)

date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)
```

I am trying to follow the instructions here : [Getting a monthly time series from weekly data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435638/getting-a-monthly-time-series-from-weekly-data)

```
y.mon  <- aggregate(final_data, by = format(date_decision_made,format="%Y/%m/%d"), FUN=sum)
```

But this code gives me an error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(final_data, by = format(date_decision_made,  : 
  'by' must be a list
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution for OP issue can be based on:

```
#Code
y.mon<-aggregate(property_damages_in_dollars~format(as.Date(date_decision_made),
format="%Y/%m"),data=final_data, FUN=sum)
```

More variants can be explored around the `format()` options.

Comment: @stats555 Thanks to you! And if the solution covered your expectations with the issue consider accepting it !

Comment: i posted another time series question - when you have time could you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162036/r-convert-dates-from-daily-to-weekly-and-plotting-them thank you!

Comment: @stats555 Doing now!

Comment: @stats555 I have added one possible solution, please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: thanks for everything! If you have some time, can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174250/r-how-to-order-the-x-axis-in-a-graph-in-chronological-order thank you! Let me know if I have to accept anything....