# How to unclutter the x-axis in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, aggregate, data-visualization

Using the R programming language, I create some time series data (daily measurements, over a period of 20 years). I aggregated this data at monthly time periods and then produced a graph:

```
library(ggplot2)

library(xts)

library(scales)

set.seed(123)

day = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2020/1/1"),by="day")

day <- format(as.Date(day), "%Y/%m/%d")

amount <- rnorm(7306 ,100,10)

data <- data.frame(day, amount)

y.mon<-aggregate(amount~format(as.Date(day),
format="%Y/%m"),data=data, FUN=sum)

y.mon$d = y.mon$`format(as.Date(day), format = "%Y/%m")`

ggplot(y.mon, aes(x = d, y=amount))+
         geom_line(aes(group=1))
```

[image]

1. Right now, the x-axis is completely unreadable. Is there a way to "unclutter" the x-axis? Perhaps "slant" the dates or show the dates at intervals of  4 month periods? I can completely delete the x-axis but ideally I would like to keep it there for reference.
2. At the end of the graph, there is a huge downwards "spike". I think this is because the data is aggregated every month - and since the last day the data is available at is "Jan-01-2020", this causes the "downwards spike". Is it possible to "query" the "y.mon" object so that the graph is made only until the last "complete" time period? This "spike" is deceiving, someone might look at the graph and think a big anomaly happened in Jan-2020, but it's actually because there is only 1 measurement at this time.

Thanks

Comment: It seems `d` is a discrete variable. Keep it `as.Date()` and change the format in `+ scale_x_date(date_labels = ...)`

Comment: do you mean : y.mon$d =as.Date (y.mon$d)   ?

Comment: I tried this earlier and got the following : y.mon$d =as.Date(y.mon$d)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(xts)
library(scales)
set.seed(123)
#Data
day = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2020/1/1"),by="day")
amount <- rnorm(7306 ,100,10)
data <- data.frame(day, amount)
#Aggregate
y.mon<-aggregate(amount~format(as.Date(day),
                               format="%Y/%m"),data=data, FUN=sum)
#Count days
y.mon2<-aggregate(amount~format(as.Date(day),
                               format="%Y/%m"),data=data,
                  FUN=function(x) length(x))
names(y.mon2)[2]<-'N'
#Format and merge to add N
y.mon$d = y.mon$`format(as.Date(day), format = "%Y/%m")`
mmon <- merge(y.mon,y.mon2)
#Add a dummy date
mmon$d <- as.Date(paste0(mmon$d,'/01'),'%Y/%m/%d')
#Plot
ggplot(subset(mmon,N!=1), aes(x = d, y=amount))+
  geom_line(aes(group=1))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '4 month',date_labels = '%Y-%m',
               expand = c(0,0))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:** Using previous code and only changing for labels:

```
#Plot Update
ggplot(subset(mmon,N!=1), aes(x = d, y=amount))+
  geom_line(aes(group=1))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '12 month',date_labels = '%Y',
               expand = c(0,0))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really like what your previous answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162036/r-convert-dates-from-daily-to-weekly-and-plotting-them (2nd graph). Could you please show me how would do this for my graph (only show a "tick" on the x-axis every year, or only show a "tick" every two years)? Thank you for everything!

Comment: @Noob Sure let me update, the key is on date breaks!

Comment: @Noob I have updated the code, please let me know if that works fine for you!

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! just for the future, how do you modify this code to label the x-axis differently? Suppose I wanted to make a "tick" twice a year (every 6 months), how would this work? I am not sure, but would you write : ggplot(subset(mmon,N!=1), aes(x = d, y=amount))+
  geom_line(aes(group=1))+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '6 month',date_labels = '%Y',
               expand = c(0,0))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) ??